# Could not insert action connection: could not find any information about the class XMTAppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

A while ago I used Xcode to create an RPN calculator for Mac. I used to interface builder and was able to use IBOutlets and IBActions. Now when I try to add an IBOutlet or IBAction I get this message:

```
Could not insert action connection: could not find any information about the class XMTAppDelegate
```

My workaround for IBOutlets is to just create them myself and then connect them. Unfortunately this does not work for IBActions. So, my question is: how to I stop Xcode giving me this message. I have read other questions from people with a similar problem but none of the solutions work. I have deleted the derived data folder. I have reinstalled Xcode. Nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean your project and restart Xcode. 
If it still cannot be connected, follow the `Utilities` navigation view of Xcode, in the `Target membership` section, **uncheck & check** the checkbox, it will be work. Maybe you should rebuild the project after unchecking.