# Apple Mach-O error only when compiling for iPhone 64-bit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

I'm using TestFlightSDK, when i run on any other simulator it works without issues, **only** when i test against iPhone 5s simulator (( **64-bit** )) i get an error about testflight lib and pod project :\
This is the error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/lightdream/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PECO-gwvmtuvxtbegjiasbpanfvzmzery/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386):
>   /Users/lightdream/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PECO-gwvmtuvxtbegjiasbpanfvzmzery/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFSideMenuContainerViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

I don't knew how this happened, and couldn't figure it out :\

Note: the files are there, and it's compiling against all other simulators, ( including ipad ), it's not missing files thing, it doesn't find the library **only on iPhone(64-bit) simulator**.

Comment: MFSideMenuContainerViewController is missing ,check it all .m file is active

Comment: no no, it's there, this MFSideMenuContainerViewController is there, it's in the pod project, else it wouldn't compile against the other iOs simulators !!

Answer (score 0):

Check your build phase and make sure you have all the `.m` files and `.a` lib files are there

Comment: Do you have the same problem on device too? try to delete your Xcode data folder and clean your build

Comment: unfortunately i don't have a device. where can i find Xcode data folder ?!? and i did clean my build, nothing changes.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder