# xcode jump to wrong definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode5.1

I have a file named SysConfig.h and its has the following function

```
+ (void)setValue:(NSString*) key float:(float) value;
```

When I use this function in AppDelegate.m like

```
[SysConfig setValue:@"AA" float:1.0];
```

and select "setValue" to jump to its definition, Xcode jumps to UISlider.h

```
@property(nonatomic) float value;
```

When debugging the program step by step, I cannot step into some of the functions that created by me.
Even cleaning the project didn't help.
Does anyone have any ideas?
My code is executable and works fine in Xcode 5.0. However, when I upgrade to Xcode 5.1, that problem
happened.

Tested on Xcode 5.1, iOS SDK 7.1

Update:

When I refactor->Rename the setValue to setFloatValue, and click jump to definition, 
it becomes "Symbol Not Found"

Comment: did you actually `#include` or `#import` SysConfig.h in AppDelegate.m?

Answer (score 1):

There's a setter for [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/value) on `UISlider` so I imagine Xcode is just picking that up. 
You could try renaming the method and see if the problem still happens?

It might be clearer to name it

`+ (void)setFloatValue:(CGFloat)value forKey:(NSString *)key;`

Anyway as it then follows the usual Objective-C convention. As your original definition seems to use the value and key interchangeably!

Comment: Try closing the project and then deleting its [derived data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder).

Comment: so sad Rich. Deleting the derived data and clean-rebuild the project is still not working

Comment: Yes, there is no build errors and the program is executable! just unable to jump to the definition

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like Xcode just isn't indexing the project correctly (or maybe hasn't finished if its a big project). I've had this a few times and I think it just went away. Not much help! You could possibly try restarting the machine but that seems like a last ditch attempt. Least the program works! :)