# Error: "Could not build module AVfoundation" on Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode, build, module, frameworks, linker-errors

I encountered a weird problem.

I added the framework AVfoundation to the project, and included the header file as the third line below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

But I got "Could not build module AVfoundation" error when I tried to build the project.

I started a new project, then everything was alright. But several days later, the same problem occurred again.

The Xcode is Version 5.1 (5B130a).

Restarting Xcode or the computer do not solve the problem.

Comment: I updated Xcode to Version 5.1.1 (5B1008), and the problem disappeared  automatically for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem but was able to solve it :

1. Just Clear The Derived Data Contents([Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder) ) From Xcode.
2. Quit and Restart XCode.