# Xcode 5.1.1 could not build module "AVFoundation" while archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have a crazy problem, that I don't understand.

When I build and run my app for my device it's work probably. But I wanted to upload a new update with just a few changes.

I ran into one error saying:

> Could not build module 'AVFoundation'

It's implemented like this:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

My Deployment Target is iOS 7.0 and my base sdk is iOS 7.1. When I change the Deployment Target to iOS 7.1 it's working?! Why?
Also when I remove arm64 from the architectures it's working.

What should I do? I don't want to set the deployment target so high :/

Hope you guys have some clues.

Thanks in advance and best regards from Germany, 
Chris

Comment: Hi @Christian Pappenberger: Have u found any solution for this.Am getting same issue while am archiving in xcode 6 with ios 8.1..

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem but was able to solve it :

1. Just Clear The Derived Data contents([Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder) ) From Xcode.
2. Quit and Restart XCode.

Comment: Hi @Dheeraj Singh : i have tried above solution but its not working for me

Comment: @sabir what error are u getting ? The error same above .Can u tell in more detail.