# Xcode 6 beta 2 doesn't tell me what is causing build failed

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a very big issue with Xcode 6. When there is a red error, it doesn't tell me what is causing it. It simply says red1, build failed, and when I press on the error I get redirected to Project -> general even if has nothing to do with that. When I get a line of code wrong, it does the same. It seems that my copy of Xcode has lost the ability to see errors. Furthermore just recently, my AppDelegate.m file has lost its "magic". When I edit it I do not get suggestions any more, neither errors. Has this happened to you?

PS: I have already tried restarting my mac and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Try deleting derived data, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder

Comment: Try a command-option-k (force clean)

Comment: When the problem is logs I recommend quitting Xcode, too, @Undo. :)