# Xcode project does not build/run with core data when target is my iPhone 5c

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, building

Xcode 5.1.1. - iOS7

When I create an empty project with Core Data option checked (literally empty project - nothing at all), it never builds! It takes 7-10 minutes for "indexing" and then says "build failed" with one error: "Could not build module 'CoreData'".

It works fine if I switch the target to the (3.5-inch Retina iOS simulator) or (4-inch Retina iOS simulator). 
It does NOT work with (4-inch Retina 64-bit Simulator) or my iPhone 5c.

Any project with no Core Data option works fine on my iPhone 5c and the (4-inch Retina 64-bit Simulator). So, my profile and provisioning settings are all fine!

Any help?!

Comment: Why does the build fail? Post the errors the prevent the app from running.

Comment: I updated the question. It says "Could not build module 'CoreData'". 
Thanks.

Comment: Try this, create a master-detail project template. Change the target to iOS 7 and see if everything doesn't work at that point. Make sure that works. Next remove the stuff you don't want from the storyboard. If you want to work without a storyboard then just dump it but be prepared to rebuild your initialization classes.

Comment: Tommie, Thanks for answering but the project was already empty. The approved answer below solved it. Thanks you though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Build Settings -> Architecture -> Architectures and change the option to standard architecture ( armv7 , armv7s ).

Clean the project (CMD+Shift+K) and if it still not working, clean the derived data (see how: [Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder))

If it still doesn't work, try to remove the CoreData framework and add it again.

Comment: Sebyddd, you saved my life! THANKS!
I found that the architecture option was set to standard so I didn't change that. But deleting the derived data made it! Thanks, man :)