# Meteor cordova ios project pch errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

I've been working on a Meteor project using Cordova to build an iOS app. It was working very smoothly for a while and then all of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
❯❯❯ meteor run ios         

Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running
/Users/chet/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.37.19du6bc++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
2014-12-23 13:35:00.970 xcodebuild[46060:3143193] error: InputFile    /Users/chet/Code/meteor/5cmenu/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/5C Menu/5C
Menu-Prefix.pch 0 1418992636 959 33188... malformed line 9; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments
```

If I open the `.xcodeproj` in `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/`, the project runs just fine. However, its an old version of my meteor app.

I tried deleting `.meteor/local`, then `meteor run ios`. I get the same error. And when I opened the `.xcodeproj`, it worked when I tried running it.

I also tried `meteor remove-platform ios` then `meteor add-platform ios`. Then I ran `meteor run ios`. I get the same error, but again, when I opened the `.xcodeproj`, it worked.

Theres a similar [issue posted here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3105
).

A couple things I've tried are [deleting the Xcode DerivedData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder), and cleaning my Xcode build cache for the project by running `cmd+shift+K` which seems totally unnecessary for this problem.

I also [found a similar issue here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2394#issuecomment-56658587) that said this is a "non-fatal error".

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of the ways reset your Xcode build is with `rm -rf .meteor/local/`. Then `meteor run ios-device` will build a new project. However, when you do this, you end up with his PCH error because of some sort of caching.

You'll find a path in your error that looks something like this

```
/var/folders/x5/mdr8syvj7lsb_sg_pr0j7y_h0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/
```

Notice the `SharedPrecompiledHeaders` part. Delete the app that starts with your app name. Then do this all over

```
rm -rf .meteor/local/
meteor run ios-device
```

Works every time

Comment: Instead of `rm -rf .meteor/local/` you can `meteor reset`

Comment: not sure that does the same thing... i think reset just throws out mongo

Comment: In the current documentation doesn't specify anything besides deleting the database but indeed deletes your local build, you can check yourself that after a reset,  `.meteor/local/` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your path, which is being interpreted as another argument.

/Users/chet/Code/meteor/5cmenu/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/**5C Menu**/5C

More info here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3105#issuecomment-75580362