# Why is compiler reporting SDWebImageManager defaultCachePathForKey not found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, sdwebimage

I am seeing the compiler warn that "Instance method -cacheKeyForURL not found" and "Instance method -defaultCachePathForKey not found", in the following code:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
NSString *cacheKey = [manager cacheKeyForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
NSString *cachePath = [[manager imageCache] defaultCachePathForKey:cacheKey];
```

[image]

Yet clearly, these methods are defined. Here, for example, is the [method definition in SDImageCache.h](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h):

```
/**
 *  Get the default cache path for a certain key
 *
 *  @param key the key (can be obtained from url using cacheKeyForURL)
 *
 *  @return the default cache path
 */
- (NSString *)defaultCachePathForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

At the top of my code file, I am including the relevant files from the SDWebImage project:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import <SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h>
#import <SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.h>
```

Moreover, `sharedImageManager` [is defined](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.h#L176) in `SDWebImageManager.h` and the compiler is having no problems finding it. I only have warnings on the 2nd and 3rd lines.

My code runs fine and these methods both work without crashing. Why is the compiler telling me it cannot find it?

I am running XCode 6, compiling for Active Architecture Only, iPhone 6 Simulator.

UPDATE

When I compile for Distribution, "All Architectures", suddenly it can find `cacheKeyForURL` and `defaultCachePathForKey`, no problem, but `setImageWithURL` is now deprecated?

[image]

I do see the [deprecation warnings in UIImageView+WebCache.h](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h#L184), but I'm just super-confused why building for these different architectures is turning on/off various compiler warnings when the header files of SDWebImage don't seem to have anything architecture-specific to them.

Comment: are you using which version of `SDWebImage`? In new version there is a `sd_setImageWithURL`.So can you confirm this. you can use from this linkhttps://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Version 3.7.1, according to Podfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by more closely inspecting the error in the "Report Navigator" (neé [Log Navigator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-log_navigator/articles/log_navigator-about.html)).

[image]

It turns out that there were some very old SDWebImageManager.h files in the "Derived Data" folder that it was choosing to link against. Unclear why they did not go away upon a clean of my project. (Possibly connected to the fact that I migrated from submodules to including SDWebImage via Cocoapods?)

I [used this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder) to navigate to my DerivedData folder, and then I manually deleted the subfolder for my project. After doing that, the project now builds successfully without the spurious warnings.