# how do I delete an app from the organizer left menu

Tags: xcode

I want to remove an app from the xcode organizer window in the left menu.  I deleted it from `~/Users/Library/Developer/xcode/Product` but it keeps reappearing both in the organizer and in that folder everytime I click on the crashes tab in the organizer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove apps from Organizer in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091608/how-can-i-remove-apps-from-organizer-in-xcode)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to remove the App's archive's from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` along with `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products` to remove it from Xcode's Organizer completely.

Comment: Finder didn't open, found out it is `Xcode` (capitalized) for me. Maybe it's the same for you but I didn't want to edit your answer in case I missed something

Comment: Not a valid location. Use `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products` as per @iamfaizuddin 's answer

Answer (score 8):

1. Delete the apps from **Xcode Organiser** by going to  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products` and deleting the folders from there.
2. Close and reopen the Organiser.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Xcode > Window > Organizer, right click on an archive and click open in finder, then press Command + DPadUp to move up a folder and see all the archives. I had 120GB.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on **XCode 12.X**. Follow the below steps

1. Remove the Archives files by right click on apps archive files and `Delete Archive`.
2. open in finder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products` and Delete bundle id folder which you want to delete.

**This works 100%**