# Xcode 8.3 Organizer ios app name issues

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok, first I am not a mac person.

I build/deploy apps to the app store for my company. The previous dev was let go, the new devs are overseas. I just updated xcode to 8.3, it said that it needed it for debugging.

We developed a cookie cutter type app. A few image changes and text changes and we have a new app.  Each app has its own App Id(example com.marketingco.bobsstore.OwnerApp), profiles, etc.  Before the update, in the organizer the left column displayed each app name (display name a field in the .plist file, Bobs Store), with each build called was OwnerApp.

Now the OwnerApp is appearing in the left column for every new build I make. No special schemes are used. They still upload to the app store without issue.

Anyone else seeing this problem? It is not critical, but it is very annoying.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you able to provide an image which shows what you currently see in the Organizer?

Comment: Strange, booted up this morning and all has returned to normal.

Comment: Xcode seems to have trouble sometimes after you've been running it for a while. Restarting Xcode seems to fix a lot of issues :)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091608/how-can-i-remove-apps-from-organizer-in-xcode. Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products` and Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`