# Linker error after changing app name?

Tags: xcode

We have changed the app name by clicking on its name on the left in `Xcode`, and than rename it.

Now we have this error : (see the app name and previous app name-that i have edited)

```
ld: file not found: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-auangpcpnpkqkgbdbtzbecxqxadg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/previousappname.app/previousappname
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried this :
Under `test target, build settings` i changed :

```
Testing/test host:
Debug: changed to new app name
Release: changed to new app name
```

Comment: Deleted your derived data?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder .

Comment: thanks, but in your link,its not my case(??)

Comment: @Curnelious, did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.  I've tried everything!