# After installing Xcode 7, Xcode 6.3 shows errors about converting to Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

After installing Xcode 7 to play with Swift 2 in Playgrounds, I've got a weird problem:

when I open an existing Xcode 6.3 project with Xcode 6.3, it throws lots of errors about conversions to Swift 2.

This project was just cloned from the repository and hasn't been opened with Xcode 7 yet.

So my guess is that the Xcode 7 install messed up the Xcode 6.3 installed tools or something like that, but I have no idea how I could start to fix this.

I certainly don't want to open and upgrade this big project in Xcode 7 at the moment, but I do need to open it in Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 to continue work on it.

Comment: try clearing the caches and the derived data

Comment: Thank you Leo, number of errors went down from 200+ to just 2 after cleaning caches and build. :) Xcode still refuses to build the embedded frameworks, though: no biggie I guess, I'm going to delete them from the project and reinstall them with CocoaPods (they were manually installed previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Leo's comment, I was able to [clean the caches and derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder), and these errors went away.

But then Xcode refused to build the project's included frameworks (SQLite.swift and SwiftHTTP) even after cleaning everything and rebooting.

I had to uninstall them manually, clear the "build phase" and "target" fields where they appeared, then use CocoaPods to reinstall them.

After that, my app compiled again properly in Xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on product in menubar
2. Click Clean
3. Then try reBuild project by click on play botton

it works for me