# How to load an image into an Xcode 9 playground?

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I've spent hours trying to simply gain access to image data in my Swift Playground.  I've followed many tutorials that recommend adding a resource folder as a sibling dir in the dir. your playground is in.  Or to drag images into the Resources folder in the playground Navigator.  Nothing has worked.  What do I have to do to load an image view in playground?

Comment: These methods work. Show us why they don't work for you: screenshots of your playgrounds may help finding the issue, for example. Also, open the playground's debug area and tell us what are the error messages.

Comment: there are no errors.  the sources and resources folders are simply greyed out.  dragging images into them has no effect.  I have employed the methods I described before and has success.  I'm not sure why it isn't working now.  I am using Xcode8 and Xcode9 on the same machine and that often causes problems with simulators.  I wonder if switching back and forth is somehow corrupting playgrounds in some way.

Comment: Switching between Xcode versions may cause issues - I know it happened to [me in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30752203/2227743). // How about image literals? You just drag the image from the Finder to the playground *into the code editor, next to your variable - not in the Resources folder*, the playground will import the file itself. Does it work? Like you do `let img =` and you drop the image from Finder just next to the `=`.

Comment: THAT was actually working but when i tried `let img = THAT` i got errors

Comment: now it seems  that `let a = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "big.png")` is working. at least this was not working.. `let a = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "big.png")
let im = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: a)`

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem on my side when I

1. `import PlaygroundSupport`
2. mark *Resources* Folder and tap **+** icon
3. Choose *Add files to 'Resources'* and choose your image (here: *image.jpg*)
4. Instance your image via `let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")`

**Xcode 12 Preview**

[image]

Comment: FYI: Using Xcode 9.2.3, the display of the image (inline in the grey rounded-rect) required tapping on the "Show Result" (looks a bit like an iconized computer CRT) on the far right side.

Comment: This worked for me in Xcode 12.5.1, too. Adding "import PlaygroundSupport" was a step not included in a much older SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage