# How to add an image in Playground as I would like to apply and test CIFilters?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am trying to use playground to import images so that I can test CIFilters.  I am unable to import any images.  My image is in the same folder as my playground file. Please see screen shot.

PLAYGROUND CODE:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class myView: UIViewController{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage.init(named: "scan.jpg")
        let imgView = UIImageView.init(image: image!)
        view.addSubview(imgView)
    }


}
```

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636060/how-to-load-an-image-into-an-xcode-9-playground

Comment: How do I mark 'resources' folder? I'm sorry , but I found that answer not very clear

Comment: Press first icon from the left of Navigators, then you will see Left side menu from there you have to add your image in Resources directory

Comment: I dragged an image to the 'Resources' folder, but I don't see the file on the left hand side

Comment: Could you please add a snapshot for the left side

Comment: please see update

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, just drag+drop your image or in the same directory press + in the bottom to add it