# facing this error while building a project in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

facing this error while building a project in xcode

```
warning: unable to merge a subprocess's serialized diagnostics
error: unable to open output file '/Users/s-09/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ls-cujvtldtpxrezhdhbujnmfcrntjl/Build/Intermediates/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVPluginResult.o': 'Error opening output file '/Users/s-09/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ls-cujvtldtpxrezhdhbujnmfcrntjl/Build/Intermediates/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVPluginResult.o': Input/output error'

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try removing your /DerivedData, clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning the /DerivedData made it work

> [Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/)

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced that problem. I have closed, restarted Xcode; deleted the application from device and reinstalled it again, then the problem has gone.
Make sure the library and project files is truly included if it is not include it shows in red color in this type of case some time it is in original folder and not in project so delete it and add it again.

Comment: i tried this it didn't work, but cleaning the dervieddata folder worked like a breeze.