# unable to open executable Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ myAppTests.xctest/MyApp For AppTests': No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, swift

I get an error when I'm trying to build my App saying that Xcode is unable to find some file (xctest files i believe).
FYI: I recently changed the name of the project from the sidebar in Xcode and it asked me if wanted to update the name of all the other files as well and I said yes so it probably has something to do with that.

Anyone ever experienced that?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very nominal error. To solve the error:

> Clean the project
>
> Delete the derived data
>   [Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)
>
> Delete "XCTest.Framework" file from Project Navigator > Targets >
>   'Project Name' > Build Phases

Comment: Sorry but i don't find the xctest.framework in building phases

Answer (score 0):

Try    cmd + shift + K   to clean