# expected an objective-c directive after '@'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I am integrating XMPP Framework in my project. While i compile the project i got one issue i.e `expected an objective-c directive after '@'`
 in XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.h Class.

```
//XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>



@class XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject;
@interface XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet* users;
+ (void)clearEmptyGroupsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
+ (id)fetchOrInsertGroupName:(NSString *) groupName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
+ (id)insertGroupName:(NSString *) groupName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;


@end
```

While compile the code i got issue, please have a look in screenshot
[image]

Comment: I have done this so many times. But not succeed.

Comment: What is the implementation file which is being compiled when you get this error? It has probably `#define`d `groupName` to something or imported a header which has. Show the lines of that source file up through where it imports this header. You might also ask Xcode to preprocess that source file and examine what those lines have been turned into.

Comment: if you have same name constants in this 2 classes which could cause this error, please check that and let me know if it's fix?

Comment: may be a broken unicode problem, try to delete g,space,), and retype it ") g"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile your source code, no errors.
Try clear project **(Product -> Clean)** and derived data, it should help.

[how to clear derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/4948877)