# Can't start app, "process launch failed: No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I'm running Xcode 7, I fire up a blank project and try to run it. It installs on my device but does not open initially, I get an error

```
error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9EC2E8EE-AE9F-46B9-8740-2CB07C3AFFBC/Discovr.app' -- process launch failed: No such file or directory (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9EC2E8EE-AE9F-46B9-8740-2CB07C3AFFBC/Discovr.app)
```

I'm not sure as to what this means, but I've already tried restarting and cleaning. I've tried looking around for a fix, but no results yet. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the app from your device, then quit Xcode and delete the Derived Data just as explained in this question:

[Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)

And then, run again.

Hope it helps.