# Apple Mach-O Linker Error for Objective C Bridging

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to bridge an Objective-C file to Swift, and I've done everything outlined in this Apple tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Regardless, I go to run my app, and the build fails every time, complaining to me about a Mach-O Linker Error.

This is the exact error message:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LeDiscovery", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in LeDataService.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Clean your  derived data folder and try again

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

GO to your `Target -> Select your project -> Build Settings`

set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `NO`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `arm64` to your valid architectures.

> Target -> Build Settings -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures

my valid architectures are:

```
arm64 armv7 armv7s
```