# I changed the name of my project in Xcode, now when I run it I got an error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling, runtime-error

The name of my app was **Free Percentage Calculator**, I didn't want that long name to show in the home screen below the app when downloaded so I changed the **'Identity and Type'** name to **Percentage Calculator**. I'm ready to take the screenshots the app store and when I ran the app i got this **issue**:

---

**( ! ) Apple Mach-O Linker Error**

- *Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

---

### **WHAT SHOULD I DO?**

****sorry but for a reason stack overflow doesn't let me upload an image****

Comment: Diid you try cleaning your project?

Comment: no just this one, should I rename it again but with the original name?

Comment: did you try clearing derived data? usually when I get this error I just clear derived data and restart xcode and it solves itself.

Comment: BTW - there was no reason at all to rename anything. All you needed to do was update the "Bundle Display Name" in the Info.plist. That's it.

Comment: somebody commented to "clean", and somebody else to "clear"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder this might help with trying the deriveddata thing. no promises it works though.

Comment: As far as i can tell, i think there is no issue with the derived data.  
You may face the above error due to some invalid path of a library, or source files. 
This is because when you change the name of the project, and your project is pointing to some external resources, you may face this error!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,
just changed the name back exactly how it was before.
Thanks everybody for giving your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Cmd - shift - K should clean the environment and get rid of that error.

This usually works for me. Hopefully this helps.