# Renamed a class in Xcode, now getting "Expected a type" when building

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Using the Refactor->Rename utility in Xcode I renamed a class to be more accurate to what it is.  Now when I try to build my project I get a compiler error "Expected a type" in one of my header files when it tries to build one of the Today Extension projects.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Timetable.h"

@interface NSString (Extras)

- (NSString *)CountdownLabelWithSchedule:(Timetable *)sch;

@end
```

Xcode is telling me that the error is with the Timetable reference on the last line.  There's nothing interesting in Timetable that I think could cause this problem.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Timetable : NSObject

// Just some NSString & BOOL properties

@end
```

In the today extension's target under Build Phases->Compile Sources I have `Timetable.m` included.

I tried cleaning the project and deleting the derived data, but it didn't work.

Comment: The error is probably elsewhere, perhaps a missing @end in one of your interface files. Try removing the `countDownLabelWithSchedule` method from your interface file and see if it builds. If it doesn't you will have a pointer to where the real culprit is.

Comment: Well, no it wont build because I use that method.  Both timetable and NSString extras have `@end`, I just didn't include them in the post.

Comment: What if you try adding `@class Timetable` to that category extension interface? Does it build?

Comment: try clean or [delete DerivedData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)

Comment: @BryanChen please read my entire post, I tried that already.

Comment: @Rog Yes, it builds now.  But why did this work fine without the `@class` before the rename?

Comment: You shouldn't need that, I just wanted to see if that really was the root cause of your issue and it seems to be. Now are you 100% positive your `Timetable` class is sentence case as you typed here? Could it be that you refactored it to be `TimeTable` or something along those lines? Is the code above verbatim / copy&paste from your class?