# Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

Getting this errors when i build the application

```
 Main.storybord: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach  "/var/folders/v5/4tnjcvds103g1y3tf1mnfv680000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-10-30_11-30-47_678000".
```

And

```
 LaunchScreen.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach all crash logs from ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.
```

[image: here is the image]

Done all things Cleaning project, Quit Xcode Several times and also restarted the System, Still getting errors.

Any one got solution help me please ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373683/xcode-storyboard-internal-error-please-file-a-bug

Comment: have you seen crash reports at ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports ?

Comment: @V-Xtreme Ya seen one Crash report with my project name in User Diagnostic Reports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373683/xcode-storyboard-internal-error-please-file-a-bug)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try following options to clean up the build files :

**cmd + shift + k**

AND

**cmd + option + shift + k**

OR

even you can send the bug report on [this link](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3) for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue,

Solution was: clearing out the `DerivedData` folder.
Can be found in  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue when i have updated my launch screen into project.

I just do following things the issue got cleared.

1.Get the back up of your source code.

2.Delete your LaunchScreen.storyboard file.

3.Pop up will appear and it will ask re save the storyboard file or close option,press close.

4.Just Add LaunchScreen.storyboard file into your current project from your back up source code.

5.Now clean then build , issue will cleared.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

All this is not work for me or for you????

Waring:You can do this

The reason is you download Simulators on the new Xcode, you must delete it!!
the path is "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes"

For example your xcode version is Xcode 8.0, Now you download Xcode 9.0, You have two xcode, you download ios 10 Simulator on the Xcode 9.0, Then Xcode 8.0 will appear the Storyboard can't run, Because, Xcode 8.0 default Simulator is ios 10, Conflicted!!!