# I am getting this error in Xcode 7.1. Filing a bugreport and attach */var.. IB-agent diagnostics

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am totally clueless about what does this error mean? This is the first time I am getting an error that tells me to file a bug to bugreport.applecom and IB-agent-diagnostics given with the time stamp[image: Here is the snapshot of the internal error I am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373683/xcode-storyboard-internal-error-please-file-a-bug) it may help you to fix your issue.

This is the answer written in that link.

```
I faced the same issue. And it was solved by cleaning up the build files.

    cmd + shift + k

AND

    cmd + option + shift + k
```

Answer (score 0):

Please `cmd+shift+k` multiple times, It appears many times in xcode 7. If you face this issue again, please `quit xcode` and then try `cmd+shift+k`