# Main.storyboard: Internal error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

While changing constraints in storyboard, suddenly encountered this error when I wanted to run the project.

Previously my project was running fine, but after updating `XCODE` to `7.2` i am getting this error

```
Main.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/jy/qk3txlvd1nxc3305l0_z73_00000gp/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-01-13_15-31-24_701000".
```

I tried `Clean Build` but still no success

And now I can't run my project anymore. Did anyone encounter this before?

Comment: Quit Xcode ->Restart your system->open Xcode->Clean->build->run

Comment: it seems like the same issue -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373683/xcode-storyboard-internal-error-please-file-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few attempts to answer this question, mostly by first clearing build files (cmd + shift + k AND cmd + option + shift + k), and restarting your machine.   But in my situation none of these helped.

Rebuilding the entire storyboard wasn't an option as it was so large, so the only way is taking the hard approach of finding the actual elements causing the issue.  Then deleting just those, and recreating.

I would recommend this binary approach:

- Zoom out to the largest screen on the storyboard, select half of all the screens, delete, and recompile.  Depending if it fails or succeeds, CMD+Z to undo, take the failing half and try again.
- Once you narrow it down to a single view (hopefully it will be a single view!), do the same with the elements inside the view.

Takes a short while, but far better then recreating the entire storyboard.