# Xcode - Can't run app on simulators, or on phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I was trying to run my project on Xcode, but I found that when I hit Command-R, Xcode would say the app had built, and was running, but after 3 minutes, it still hadn't appeared on the simulator. I ran it again, and it did the same thing, so I force-quit Xcode, and reloaded it. When I had reloaded Xcode, all the simulators had disappeared, and when I try to run the app on my phone, Xcode starts building, and then just stalls when processing one of the XIB files.

I have tried going to Windows->Devices to reinstall a simulator, but Xcode just freezes when I do this.

It seems I have royally screwed my developer environment by force-quitting while it was building. How can I fix this?

All help app-reciated.

Comment: try deleting the XCode and re-installing.

Comment: click on ios simulator-> reset content and settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder

Comment: Delete & Reinstall didn't work.

Comment: Mihir: Where is this option? I don't currently have an iOS simulator running, and cannot get one running either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to exit the simulator.
If this doesn't work try to restart the computer.
if none of them work you are screwed and should reinstall xcode

Comment: have you reset the simulators?

Comment: How do I do this? I can't get a Simulator running by any of the alternative methods, so is there any way to do this which doesn't rely on a Simulator already being open?

Comment: You can't open the simulator not from xcode?
look for "simulator" in finder

Comment: I try to run the Simulator from the Finder, but the icon in the dock simply bounces up and down endlessly, before stopping bouncing. But then I click on it in the dock, and it doesn't open. And if I long-press (right-click), it says it isn't responding.

Comment: Maybe try to install it?
Or if you have the Simulator on the finder you still need to be able to reset it

Comment: Also, when I try to open the storyboard, Xcode freezes. This, coupled with the fact that Xcode gets stuck compiling XIB files, led me to think the storyboard may be corrupted. But I replaced the storyboard with an earlier version, and it still wouldn't load the storyboard, and the simulators still wouldn't run.

Comment: I try adding a new simulator through the Xcode menu "Windows"->"Devices", but this just freezes Xcode when I hit install. Also, this would still leave my app unable to build past the stage of compiling XIB files.

Comment: On further inspection, opening the storyboard in any of my apps causes Xcode to crash. Basically, my dev environment is completely screwed, and I can't find any way to reset it, as uninstalling doesn't seem to do its job.

Comment: FIXED ^^ I downloaded the Xcode 7.2 beta. Given it's effectively an entirely new app, it has completely new settings and whatnot, allowing my Simulators and builds to run flawlessly. Also, it appears my storyboard is not corrupted. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: So, in a way, "reinstall Xcode" was the correct answer.

Comment: You welcome!
I'm glad it helped :) 
I can leave it alone now then :) 
If you can mark it as the correct answer then I will appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixes this by downloading the Xcode 7.2 beta. If you're viewing this question at a later date, download the newest beta of Xcode (or if you're using the beta, download the standard code). This version of Xcode is completely separate to the standard Xcode, allowing everything to run on normal settings.

Answer (score 0):

First try and restart Xcode, then your computer. If this does not work, reinstall the newest version of Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/