# iOS: Google Analytics duplicate symbols error

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I follow the instructions on the official site, but after all, I receive a 
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
and can't compile the project.
[image]

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After removing the derived data it disappeared. 
Here how to remove Derived Data: 
[Can I safely delete contents of Xcode Derived data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)

Comment: It's strange, because I've tryed to install this lib on two different computers, and received this error.

Comment: I also got this error but this way doesn't help me out

Answer (score 1):

If neither of the above answers did help you, remove the "Examples" folders inside Google Analytics SDK. They have other xcode projects that creates an obviously mess with your project.

[image: Examples folders in GA SDK]