# First time class name doesn't exist in autocomplete box in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

When I write the presentViewController code the first time class name does not appear in autocomplete box. So whenever I want use presentViewController, I copy the class name.

Here is screenshot
[image]

I have already declared login class but it does not appear in autocomplete.

Comment: xcode auto completion problem

Comment: remove derive data and clean your project :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder/18933382#18933382

Comment: @NitinGohel That doesn't solve Problem... I have to do that everytime for new class..

Comment: then might be that is the bug or new xcode

Comment: I have the exact same issue over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176028/xcode-7-3-1-not-autocompleting-correctly Beginning to the get the impression this is just a (relatively) serious bug in Xcode...Ugh

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build the Xcode project once you create new class, file, variable which you want import to another class.