# Xcode 7.3.1 Not Autocompleting Correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autocomplete

I have a simple, brand new Objective-C project for iOS on OSX El Capitan 10.11.4. I am using Cocoapods, so I created my Podfile with the following 3 pods: Firebase, UALogger, and AFNetworking 3.0. I installed my Pods, and then opened up the .xcworkspace. So far so good.

I have one View Controller and a subclassed UITableView, and in the VC's `.m`, I import Firebase, UALogger, AFNetworking, and my tableview as such:

```
// MyViewController.m
#import "MyTableView.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
#import <UALogger/UALogger.h>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyTableView *tableView;
```

I then go to my `viewDidLoad` method, and *attempt* to do a simple alloc/init of Firebase and create my tableview:

```
// MyViewController viewDidLoad
Firebase *firebase = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"myurl...";
self.tableView = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
```

**Here's what happens**:

- The `Firebase` class is not auto-suggested, so I have to manually type that out in both locations, but, the `initWithUrl...` *is* surprisingly auto-suggested.
- `UALogger` works as expected all the time – i.e., any time I begin typing `UA...`, it suggests the appropriate completions.
- AFNetworking classes are not auto-suggested and I have to manually type them out, but as with Firebase, the method names *are* auto-suggested.
- When I begin to create my tableview, the `MyTableView` class is not auto-suggested. That's no surprise at this point, but the notable part of this is that it is my own file, not a pod.
- As far as I can tell, Apple standard library methods are all auto-suggested as normal.

**And, to really confuse me even further**:

- If I type an **F** during mid-build (i.e., after I click the run button, but before the project finishes building), `Firebase` *will* be autosuggested. However, once the build has finished, if I backspace and then retype the letter **F**, it is no longer a suggestion. The same effect does not happen for AFNetworking or the others.

*To be clear: Everything complies, and my app runs perfectly with no warnings and no errors.*

**What I've tried thus far**:

- Setting `User Header Search Paths` in Build Settings to `$(SRCROOT)/**` (and also `"$(SRCROOT)/**"` and also `$(SRCROOT)`) along with it set to `recursive`
- Clearing out the `Header Search Paths` (and they reset to what they were before I cleared them out)
- Setting `Always Search User Paths` to `Yes`
- Ensuring the Pod public header files are in tact and correct
- Ensuring my files are part of Target Membership
- Deleted derived data
- Restarting the computer
- Cleaning the project
- Re-deleting derived data
- Re-cleaning the project
- Re-restarting the computer
- Uninstalling all pods, and reinstalling them
- Creating a second, new yet identical project, and repeating the above steps
- Uninstalling Xcode, and reinstalling it

None of this worked, and now I'm here.

The good news is that this hypothetically isn't that big of a deal – I just have to type more and work my little fingers to the bone.

The bad news is that I have no clue why this is happening and have to type more and work my little fingers to the bone.

If there is a solution to this that I have yet to try, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152726/first-time-class-name-doest-not-exist-in-autocomplete-box-in-xcode-7-3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports for Xcode go to Apple.

Comment: @Avi I'm fine with having this closed if it is, in the opinion of the SO community, a legitimate bug report for Apple. But based off many of the other questions, these types of problems do appear to end up being either a misconfiguration by the user or something "fixable" of that nature – albeit completely esoteric. So I was hoping it was the latter, but if it's the former, then yes you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and remove derive data.
You can force the Xcode to show suggestions manually by **pressing ctrl button + space bar**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I was unable to get this to work ;(

Comment: Sorry..its ctrl + space bar

Comment: The problem is that the auto-suggestion list does appear, but it fails to provide relevant suggestions based off what I type. The Crtl+Spacebar does force the suggestion view to appear, but it does not force the correct suggestions to be displayed.