# Xcode crashes when dragging the UI elements from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, storyboard

As title.

When I drag and drop the UI elements to my viewcontroller.swift then click "connect", it always crashes. I have cleaned the project and restart the computer but the problem is still there.

Strangely, the Xcode wouldn't crash in the new project.

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Crash film: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP-ufW53slM

This is the crash report.

> Process:               Xcode [1692] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               7.3 (10183.3) Build Info:
>   IDEFrameworks-10183003000000000~2 App Item ID:           497799835 App
>   External ID:       816750016 Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           Xcode [1692]
>   User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-07-13 14:32:44.972 +0800 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34) Report Version:        11 System Integrity
>   Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 7D175 UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator
>   isTeardownCounterpart:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x113617ec0 UserInfo: (null) Hints: None
>
> Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:      0x0100001f Trap Number:     133
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=555.5M
>   resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=555.5M(100%) Writable
>   regions: Total=1.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%)
>   unallocated=1.2G(100%)
>
> Model: MacBookAir3,1, BootROM MBA31.0061.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core
>   2 Duo, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.67f10 Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M,
>   NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB,
>   DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238412D47372020

Comment: Try [deleting derived data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/74815).

Comment: Are you sure the swift file you are in is the swift file that belongs to the correct controller in the storyboard? Also you cannot drag elements from the storyboard to the swift file. You `control-click` an element and connect it to the correct swift file.

Comment: @i_am_jorf I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: @tymac Yes! I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please check multiple outlet connected to same object .
Xcode->StoryBoard->OutletCollection->Referencing outlet. Remove all and reconnect

Comment: It didn't work.T_T. I'm pretty sure that I don't connect to same object.