# Error with AVFoundation on Xcode8 with watchos3

Tags: avfoundation, watchkit, swift3, xcode8, watchos-3

I have a error to import "`AVFoundation`" on **Xcode8** in my Class "class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController".
What is the reason ? , I updated my `Xcode` and have now `Watchos3`,`swift3` and `Xcode8`!

Error is "Could not build Objective-C module"

Comment: Please show us the code, explain in more details when the error occurs ("an error to import" sounds unclear)

Comment: @YakovL -It is no more Details, i just wanna import the Framework in top of the file it comes to an error while typng "import AVFoundation"...

Comment: @SteveJohn you can check my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same issue but I was able to solve it with following steps :

- Just Clear The Derived Data Contents From Xcode.
- Quit and Restart XCode.

For Clear **Derived Data** you can use following steps or another SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder).

**Step 1 :** Click on Xcode > Preferences...

[image: Step 1 :]

**Step 2 :** Select Location

[image]

**Step 3 :** Delete Derived Data from its Folder...

[image]

Hope it will help you...

Comment: @SteveJohn Pl. you can tick as answer and up vote it.... It will help other SO user to resolve..

Comment: ....the error comes again of a new Projekt i clear all Datas but nothing helps....same error

Comment: Clear you app (Command + K). Exit xcode and then clear derived Data.. It may help you.