# I am getting the following error when i am trying t o build my project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

> ld: file too small (length=0) file
>   '/Users/AshutoshP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheBouqs-arlmufhxskabmgbuixdzfozlrsph/Build/Intermediates/TheBouqs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheBouqs.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HomeVC.o'
>   for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: try by clean and run your project

Comment: Pl. check my answer.. It also explain how to clean DerivedData

Comment: @Ashutosh are get chance to check answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue but I was able to solve it with following steps :

- Just Clear The Derived Data Contents From Xcode.
- Quit and Restart XCode.

For Clear **Derived Data** you can use following steps or another SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder).

**Step 1 : Click on Xcode > Preferences...**

[image: Step1]

**Step 2 : Select Location**

[image]

**Step 3 : Delete Derived Data from its Folder...**

[image]

hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

quit your xcode delete your derived data and build again

Answer (score 0):

Usually that kind of error comes from a previous build not being cleaned up. 
You should clean your build folder :

- In Xcode, top menu bar select Product
- Hold the All key and see Clean change to Clean Build Folder

I do that before all of my build and became a reflex.