# Unable to boot the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I'm new in development for iOS. My problem was when I run my project, the simulator was with black screen and a message shows "Unable to boot the simulator". I'm working with Xcode version 7.3.1.

[image]

Comment: force quit simulator and start again

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: try to restart xcode and simulator.

Comment: Please see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory regarding data you can collect to help further triage the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Go to About this Mac > Storage > Manage > Delete XCode Cache and all old versions of iOS. Then run again

Answer (score 9):

The only thing that worked for me was deleting the simulator caches from the terminal. After that, I was able to open the simulator as usual.

```
rm -r ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the tmp folder permission will solve the problem

Open terminal -> chmod 777 tmp

Answer (score 2):

In this case, launchd is crashing when trying to launch
This could be as a result of deleting the /private/tmp folder.
To resolve this go to terminal and use this command.

**sudo mkdir /private/tmp**

**sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp**

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue today (Oct 25, 2018) while working on a computer with a Mojave 10.14.0 beta, which I believed has "expired".

Everything in the system worked well, except for the simulators. I couldn't launch any of them (iOS, tvOS...).

Upgrading the OS to 10.14 (final version) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset content and settings of simulator by clicking on the simulator tab on the top.

Comment: try to clean your derive data

Comment: Sorry what you mean by drive data ?

Comment: @user3851069 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder

Comment: Same problem. When trying to reset content and settings getting same alert

Comment: anyone has a solution to this. I am facing the same issue even when resetting the simulator