# Xcode Error: "An internal error occured. Editing functionality may be limited" For all projects

Tags: xcode9

I'm getting the following error:

> An internal error occured. Editing functionality may be limited

for all my projects I open with xcode. I've tried the solutions that I've read on here, the only thing I haven't done is restart my Mac, as I am working with macincloud. The error is there for all my old projects. How can I fix this when I'm using macincloud?

Comment: I too have the same problem

Comment: You should try to import your source code to a new XCode project, those kind of message show up when you're trying to run an xcodproject/xcodeworkspace that is built from older version

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had two versions of Xcode running on the same machine.

The Xcode-select value could be pointing to the wrong version. (For example, if you're running Xcode 9, but it's pointing to an Xcode 8 version that's also installed on your machine, you might run into this)
If this is your issue, then try changing the value to the right directory by using something like this:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

This also, however, happens if files have incorrect permissions or a library/developer file has been manually deleted.

If you have only one version of Xcode installed, try deleting the derived data of the project and force-closing + restarting Xcode, or even reinstalling the IDE. More on deleting derived data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/can-i-safely-delete-contents-of-xcode-derived-data-folder).

Let me know if any of this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend shutting down the app and then restarting. If this doesn't work, then it could be that you have to update XCode. You could also use an alternative to MacinCloud, like XCodeClub.com

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue in my Mac and the issue has been resolved by my self. I had tried all the answers and also some from other links.

At last what I did is, I checked the storyboard that I have been working as, source code. Then removed the last view controller (Scene) that I had created and been working on from that storyboard file. Then cleaned and removed derived data. Restarted Xcode. And then it was looking fyn. I think there were some issues with the constraints on a storyboard that had around 8 scenes, so that Xcode LLVM couldn't load it correctly. Thanks for the response.