# getting empty value in viewWillAppear( ) but getting valid value in viewDidLoad( )

Tags: ios, swift

When `print(mess)` is called from the `viewDidLoad` function, it prints what is expected, but when called from the `viewWillAppear` function, it gives empty output.  label also not getting updated after doing the assignment in `viewDidLoad` .Why is this?

main ViewController:

```
if segue.identifier == "temp"
{
let tovc = segue.destination as ! ADDviewcontroller1
tovc.mess = self.var1
}
```

In ADDviewcontroller1:

```
var mess: String = ""
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.infoLabel.text = mess
print(mess) //giving empty output in console
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
self.infoLabel.text = mess //label not getting updated

print(mess) //printing the required output in console
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone else changes the variable value.

Comment: you mean in main ViewController tovc.mess = self.var1

Comment: Are you sure `mess` is nil? Because in Swift non optional variables cant be assigned nil. So something really strange is happening or you haven't been descriptive enough about the problem you're facing.

Comment: Please add some hint to the print, to check from where the nil is coming, e.g. print("from viewWillAppear", mess) and print("from viewDidLoad", mess). Because I don't think the nil is coming from any of these. mess is initialized as empty string and not as optional.

Comment: @mh-itc done so before posting this question ..not included that over here

Comment: @Alex sorry! my mistake it is  giving empty output in viewWillAppear . Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code and found several mistakes, I have a working example below and think I have found your issue.

#### First viewcontroller (ViewController)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show" {
        let tovc = segue.destination as? AddViewController
        tovc?.mess = "test"
    }
}
```

*Note: I have renamed the identifier to `show`, rename it back to whatever it is at your code. Also I used the string `"test"` as a replacement for your `var1`*

In your first viewcontroller you will have to overwrite  the `prepare(for:sender:)` func with the code you provided. Note that the `!` was one space away from the `as` statement. I concatenated them and changed it into a conditional cast with `?`. This way it's more safe.

#### Second viewcontroller (AddViewController)

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!

var mess: String = ""
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.infoLabel.text = mess
    print(mess) //this is now printing 'test'
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.infoLabel.text = mess //label is now being set

    print(mess) //this is now printing 'test'
}
```

Note the extra `_` you were missing in the `viewWillAppear(animated:)` func signature. Not cohering to the signature makes it possible to not have it fired like you expect (because the system won't recognize the `viewWillAppear` as a valid override).

Running this code in the latest **Xcode (9.2)** using **Swift 4** I have no problems and can't reproduce your issue (if it ain't the missed signature of the `viewWillAppear`). I'm guessing this issue is to locale if you still run into troubles.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort @Alex ,  but still facing the same issue ..getting test printed in viewDidLoad but not in viewWillAppear

Comment: Hmm, really strange... Could you possibly share a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of the issue, maybe if we can reproduce it we can solve it.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible for a non-optional value to produce 'nil', but it may be a bug in Xcode try:

1- Clear derived data folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933382/3882414

2- Restart Xcode

3- Clean and rebuild

Comment: sorry! it was giving empty output in viewWillAppear() ..I have edited my post