# How to assign a String variable to a Label or TextField in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string

When `print(mess)` is called from the `viewDidLoad` function, it prints what is expected in the console, but when it is assigned to a `UITextField` or `UILabel`, then the assigned value is not getting reflected in the `UITextField` or `UILabel`. why is this ?

Doing this:

```
var mess: String = ""
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.infoLabel.text = mess //label not getting updated

    print(mess) //printing the required output in console
}
```

But when I am doing this its working fine

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let date = DATE()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minutes, from: date)
    temp.text = String(minutes)


}
```

Comment: `mess` is an optional  value?

Comment: @MahendraGP no not an optional variable

Comment: Check if infoLabel has reference outlet in storyboard (connections inspector)

Comment: @RahulKumar no it has no reference outlet.. but when I am trying to assign current time(minutes) its working fine

Comment: place "self.infoLabel.text = mess" in viewDidAppear() method

Comment: Make sure `infoLabel` outlet properly binded.

Comment: @RahulKumar tried this also before posting this question but not working and in console getting empty value

Comment: @RahulKumar pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151736/getting-empty-value-in-viewwillappear-but-getting-valid-value-in-viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

First assign value to mess variable then update UITextField value.
At time of assign value to UITextField in  `viewDidLoad` its have default value `""`.

```
var mess: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mess = "123"
        self.infoLabel.text = mess //label not getting updated

        print(mess) //printing the required output in console
    }
```

Comment: Try to add in viewWillAppear

Comment: @Needhi, value is getting printed in console. he has stated that already in question.

Comment: @NeedhiRoy tried this also before posting this question but not working and in console getting empty value

Comment: Check out you `IBOutlet` connection to `InfoLabel`. Try to delete connection and add again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way you can reflate `UILabel` value using `didSet`

```
var mess:String = "" {
        didSet {
            setupLabel()
      }
 }

func setupLabel() {
     self.infoLabel.text = mass
}
```

Whenever mess value change it automatically `infoLabel` value change

Comment: done this too but getting Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value