# Xcode 12.4 keeps freezing (Application not responding)

Tags: ios, xcode

Time to time, my Xcode starts freezing. Every few minutes for 5-30 seconds. I need to Force Quit as "application is not responding".

**QUESTION**
Is there any other way to fix this apart from removing connected devices as described here:
[Xcode 12.3 keeps freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309600/xcode-12-3-keeps-freezing) ?

It says that even disabling "Connect via network" can help. But is there any other way? Because lets be honest - it is super convenient to test your app on real device without cables :)

**Other things I have tried:**

- restarting Xcode
- restarting MacBook
- deleting everything in derived data folder

Comment: A reinstall might help

Comment: Lets call it "plan B" for now ;)

Comment: The issue is resolved in Xcode 12.5, which is available in beta now.

Comment: Oh, that’s awesome, @JordanH ! Thanks for letting me know. I have filed a bug for 12.4 already. Good to know it’s resolved