# Xcode stuck on startup

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Today my xcode is stack on startup, I have try to restart my MacBook several time but not helping

[image]

[image]

I have uninstall and install latest version 14.0.1 but same issue

MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)

Chip : Apple M1 Pro

Memory : 16 GB

Please can someone help for any workaround to make it up ( don't know if there is some cache to clean to make it up  ....)

I'm using xcode only to archive publish  my flutter up and I'm blocked due to this issue

Comment: Useful ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309600/xcode-12-3-keeps-freezing

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542257/xcode-freezes-hangs-on-startup-and-does-not-load-any-application

Comment: @matt I have try all of those before creating this post but not working

Comment: finally I'm able to run xcode after creating new flutter project from android Studio and open ios folder using xcode !!! don't know how this can work

Answer (score 0):

**Hello RAITON!)**
Version 14.0.1 is still not working correctly. I've been working on version 14.0.1 for two weeks.
If you are working on a real project and want stability in working with the program, install version 13.4.1.
This is the latest version of Xcode 13 and works perfectly. I went back to version 13.4.1 and have no problems. There is already a beta version of 14.1 (Beta 3), but after version 14.0.1, somehow I don't really want to update. In my opinion, it will be possible to upgrade to a more stable version of Xcode 14 at the beginning of the new year.

You can download any version here: https://xcodereleases.com/

I hope I helped you!) Have a nice day!)

Comment: I'm using xcode only to archive my flutter project, and I don't think in my case the problem come with latest version because issue starting with previous version and uninstall and install latest version did not resolve issue, it's resolved only when I create new flutter project from android Studio and open ios folder using xcode

Comment: @RAITON Hi again! :) I'm only working with Swift and faced many problems on Xcode 14.0.1... Some projects that work correctly on Xcode 13.4.1 don't want to work correctly on Xcode 14.0.1 in my case... Therefore, I decided to inform you and other people that the version of Xcode 14.0.1 does not work properly. I think in your case the problem is not Xcode, but I could be wrong. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case I'm using xcode only to archive, so the solution in my case is to create a new flutter project with Andoid-Studio and open ios folder using xcode and by Magic my xcode is able to start, again I don't know how it'd work as I'm not xcode expert :) but this is the only WA for me