# Cannot install mapbox ios sdk 10.0.0-beta.15 via SPM

Tags: ios, mapbox

Followed the instructions for installing the mapbox Maps SDK at https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/beta/maps/guides/install/ using Swift Package Manager, but it failed with the error:

Showing All Messages
artifact of binary target 'MapboxCommon' failed extraction: The operation couldn’t be completed. (TSCBasic.StringError error 1.)

Showing All Messages
artifact of binary target 'MapboxCoreMaps' failed extraction: The operation couldn’t be completed. (TSCBasic.StringError error 1.)

My first attempt said that the hash of the Mapbox Core Maps was incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue: Deleting the contents of the *DerivedData* folder like mentioned in [Mapbox Maps SDK Installation Guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/beta/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency) fixed it.

*DerivedData* folder can be accessed via Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/can-i-safely-delete-contents-of-xcode-derived-data-folder) some instructions if needed...

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I was trying to move from Cocoapods to Swift Package Manager.
So I did try to remove the pod changes w.r.t Mapbox SDK and forgot to give pod install.
So I realised that POD Dependencies have to be fetched and updated properly for Swift Package Manager to work properly.
So give 'pod install' / 'pod update' and then try to add with swift package manager.