# "Could not find any information for class named ViewController"

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

This bug has been driving me nuts since I started using Xcode (4.6.3). Whenever I try to link a Storyboard item to my code, I get the error:

> Could not find any information for class named ViewController.

This happens with custom classes as well. I've tried methods such as:

- Deleting the delegate data.
- Removing and re-adding the classes.
- Restarting Xcode.
- Reinstalling Xcode.

I can't ctrl-drag to create connections in any of my projects no matter what the class is. The same problem happens with a brand-new template application. If I type in the code manually and then ctrl-drag, I can make a working connection, but I can't add it automatically. Nothing I've been able to find so far on the Internet has helped. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you triple sure that the ViewController .m file is included in the proper target? (checkbox in the righthand inspector panel)

Comment: You have a view controller in your storyboard and specified "ViewController" for the name of the class that should be instantiated to manage the view.  Check each view controller in the storyboard: select the view controller, look at the "identity inspector" on the right-hand pane, and look at the "Custom Class" property.  If it reads "ViewController" then there's your problem.  Put in the name of the class that should manage your view controller... or put in UIViewController to get the default UIKit implementation.

Comment: I changed the custom class to "UIViewController" in the identity inspector, and was no longer able to ctrl-drag from the storyboard into ViewController.h. If I create a new class and try to ctrl-drag into it (after setting the view controller's class accordingly), I get the same "Could not find any information" error.

Comment: I had this problem, and *modifying* the auto-generated ViewController class worked for me. E.g. just add an `NSLog()` to `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923881/could-not-insert-new-outlet-connection-could-not-find-any-information-for-the-c)

Comment: In my case, I had created a View Controller named "aaa", removed the reference but did not delete. I meant to delete as well as remove reference. So I went to the file system and deleted the file there. Then I recreated a new View Controller with the same name. I did wonder if there would be a left over problem that was not obvious to me as I'm new to Swift.  I ended up doing a Build->Clean and then restarted XCode ("open myproject.xcworkspace). Then I was able to drag the outlet without error.

Answer (score 320):

What solved this issue for me was actually deleting the class from the project.

Steps:

1. In the project file explorer (left panel) find the class and right click -> Delete
2. **Remove reference** (do not move to trash as you will lose the class for good)
3. Right click on the folder that contained the class -> Add files to ...
4. Find the class you just deleted in the file system

This seems to force Xcode to link the class back into the storyboard.

Note: for me the following did **not** work:

- Closing Xcode
- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the class name from the storyboard and re-entering it

I think this is a bug on Apple's part

Comment: I also tried what is listed in this answer as not working. I also renamed the VC to something else and tried again. Still no luck.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, now I'm in a situation where none of the above works at all. Xcode is a ***

Comment: also make sure your file is in the correct folder.  i've placed mine in the same folder as the appdelegate.swift file

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me too. Xcode v 7.0.1.  I deleted the references to both the .h and the .m files, then added them again.

Comment: This issue dates back to Jul 2013, as of today May 2016 I get the same bug and fixed it with this answer. How come in so many years Apple doesn't fix it for good?

Comment: 2017 (Version 8.2 (8C38)) and still alive, Xcode SUCKS. It happens to me when you copy-paste UI staff from the storyboard from one scene to another

Comment: worked for me! Things that did not work:
1. clean

2. blow away derived data

3. close and reopen

4. remove/readd class name in IB

5. typing @IBOutlet var ... and manually linking

6. creating a new file and copy and pasting the class

7. general raging at my laptop, xcode, apple, tim cook, etc

Comment: April 19th 2018, still have this stupid bug in Xcode 9.3. Unbelievable, I'm wondering how Apple uses my 99$ per year.

Comment: Xcode 10 beta 5, still an issue (I had to join in, this was too funny scrolling through and seeing every version of Xcode)

Comment: I deleted the class completely, added it back as a new file and then tried connecting. Worked for me. Then I just added the code back manually. This worked for me. I am on XCode 11.

Comment: This issue still persists in 2021, Xcode 13.1. You still have to delete the file(not the reference, the actual file) and create a new file with whatever name and hook it up with Storyboard..

Answer (score 145):

In case anyone is still frustrated by this, there's a trick to get things working.

What I do is manually enter an outlet into my class, for example: `@IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView!`, and drag **from the code** to the view in IB or storyboard. After this, I am able to drag from IB / Storyboard to my class to make connections, assistant editors recognizes the class in "Automatic", etc...

Works every time.

Comment: @Gmeister4, if you create an outlet in your code it shows a small circle to the left of the outlet. Click and drag from that circle to the view in IB or Storyboard to make your connection.

Comment: Ah I see. Didnt realise you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: Still can't do it the proper way around, not even after this - but at least *this* works!

Comment: After writing @IBOutlet in code I was able to drag to this outlet from Storyboard (not to small circle but to blue square that appears)

Comment: It's 2017, Xcode 9.0.1 and this answer was helpful. It also needed to be done once, all next outlets can be connected with mouse.
What's worse, it is possible that all other answers are equally good, but we have to pick one working in particular configuration.

Comment: It has to be one of the most annoying "little" bugs I've encountered. It's just habit now to perform the above whenever Xcode forgets how to behave.

Comment: Tried to restart and didn't work,  then added manually entered like above and didnt work. Restarted again and it worked!!

Comment: still a bug in 2018, this fixed it. Filing a radar with Apple, this is ridiculous.

Comment: Sometimes it feels like Xcode do not know what to do :| but I am glad that you know what to do (Y)

Comment: It's so annoying that Xcode constantly seems to be working against you. How can this "IDE" still be so horrible!?

Comment: Still persist on 2023 with Xcode 15.0.1, this answer fix the problem.

Answer (score 43):

For me removing them from your target membership in the right column and adding them again did the trick 
[image]

Comment: This also worked from me. I had duplicated the ViewController.swift class, and this seems to be the solution.

Comment: I think it's a bug of Xcode which still exist in Xcode 8.0

Comment: This happened right now to me in Xcode 8.3.3 and your solution is the simplest and works. So thank you!!!

Comment: Still exist in Xcode 11.5 (I mean seriously Apple??). Only solution which worked for me listed here.

Comment: Works on Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 13):

Sometime Xcode does due to VC not referencing class file. The simple solution for this is:

write property manually as given.

```
class YourClassName{

     @IBOutlet weak var YourTableName: UITableView!

}
```

This will make a empty link sign **before @IBOutlet**, open your project in assistant editor then click link sign [image] and drag into the View which you want to connect (i have connected with TableView). and thats it. Enjoy Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 8):

I tried everything and it didn't work, so for me what worked is:

- Clean Build folder and project.
- Open Projects (Window -> Projects)
- Find your project on the list and delete the Derived Data
- Close Xcode
- Restart computer (without choosing to reopen windows that are open)
- run Xcode
- Work!

All my view controllers were not being recognized, so deleting all files and re-adding was not an option as this is a big project.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this problem on April 2017 with Xcode 8

Simply creating an outlet through code and compiling fixed it. eg:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

You got to love Xcode…

Edit: Still happening on Xcode 9

Answer (score 7):

the following steps works for me hope that works for you also

1- You need to reopen you project after closing Xcode.

2- Wait for indexing project files

3- Check if it work or not

4- If still not working follow step 5, if not happy for you :)

5- Clean and Build your project target

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had to do a combination of a couple of the answers so far:

1. Remove the custom class name from the storyboard.

(Click the yellow button at the top left of the view controller in the storyboard -> go to the identity inspector (option + command + 3) -> delete the custom class name at the top)

2. Remove the reference to the view controller file.

(Right-click the file -> delete -> remove reference)

3. Add the view controller file back to the project.

(Right click the folder where the file was -> "Add file to [project]")

4. Add the custom class name back to the storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the following worked:

1. Do a 'clean' and a 'clean build folder' (press 'option' on the Product menu to get the 'clean build folder' command
2. Stop Xcode
3. In terminal, go to the derived data folder:

   (/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)

Delete the derived data dir for your project.

4. Wave dead chicken in the air
5. Start Xcode

Answer (score 3):

If people try the above and things are still not working, the strange trick that worked for me was adding the outlet in a chunk of whitespace. It works if there are no other lines directly above or below the line you're adding. Strange, but it worked!

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was, instead of dragging the connection from the button to the code, was:

1. Clicking the desired storyboard item.
2. Opening the connection inspector (right panel)
3. Dragging from the + circle to the area of code.
   Like so:
   [image]

after I linked my code in this way, it worked normally from thereafter.

Answer (score 3):

Stay On Target!

I was adding a new class with a Xib and I started seeing this issue and I spent a goodly time looking through the answers on here and seeing if any of it made a difference to it.

As it happens, I have multiple targets in my workspace and often I have to switch between them.

Turns out adding new files will kick start a re-index in Xcode. But if you are pointing at the wrong target then the indexing is likely to meaningless and during the drag to connect Xcode will not be able to find your class.

In short

Step 1.

[image: Target Seledction]

Make sure you have the correct target set so that indexing makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Perform '**Clean build folder**'
   (press and hold the 'option' key and go to the "**Product**" menu to access it.
2. Perform a simple "Clean" (CMD-SHIFT-K) from the "**Product**" menu.
3. **Build** the project to let Xcode compile the files. Also, let it index files if necessary.

On a side note, I am not sure if this helped but I also deleted the **Derived data** before performing the above steps (Xcode preferences > Locations)

Answer (score 2):

Select the ViewController in storyBoard, delete current value in **Right hand panel**/"Customer class"/"class" then re-add control class (type: "SampleViewController"...), enter.
--> That work for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of these answers, the problem for me was related to Xcode not being able to index the files. I fixed this by simply quitting Xcode and reopening the project. Of course I did that after trying all of the above solutions :p

Answer (score 2):

Product > Clean (Command - Shift - K) fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

This is the EASIEST step that I did to fix this problem.

1. I clean the project
2. Drag a new button in the view controller.
3. Build the project.
4. Connect the newly dragged the button to the class (either outlet or action).
5. Then voila!!! Other outlets can now be connected to the class again!

Answer (score 1):

As my testing experience,if you delete a class which was associated in the Xcode,and than add file again,than this issue will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this happens to me I just haven't saved the code for the class yet.  Just hop over to the code and hit cmd+s and it often fixes the problem right way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys saw almost all top answers and none worked for me.

So what worked for me is the following:

1. Copy the `Derived Data` address from your Xcode project.
   This can be done using the following:

`Xcode -> Preferences -> Location Tab -> Derived Data`

2. `Close Xcode`
3. Now go to the derived data location and delete the folder of your project there.

Now open Xcode and voila!

Answer (score 1):

Just need to clean and re-build the project.

Answer (score 1):

None of the steps above worked for me, but I think I may have discovered the issue.  At least it is what worked for me, and it is not a bug in Xcode.

When in the assistant editor look at the top of the window that has the code for your viewController.  The third option from the right likely says "Manual", but it should say "Automatic".  Once I changed this, the problem was resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I just restart Xcode and then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar problem, "Could not find a class named..." and the cause was stupid on my part once I figured it out. Make sure you aren't dragging from the item to the **interface** - make sure it's being dragged to the class itself

Answer (score 1):

I tried EVERYTHING!

Make sure the class name of your UIViewController does not contain the word "Test"

Bug Report submitted.

Comment: Definitely not saying that this is the only cause.  Just that this is another thing to be aware of.

Comment: Help for me delete all derived data, clean project. But this is bug and you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remake the .m and .h files in question and give them an original name, not generic like "ViewController". Try something more along the lines of what you want that file to do, and ending in View Controller (i.e. "PizzaDecoraterViewController")

Then select the ViewController that you want to connect to those files. Make sure that you select the ViewController, not just an object within. Click the black bar at the bottom (the one that has the "First Responder" and "Exit" icons). The entire ViewController should outline blue. Then go to the Custom Class section in the Identity Inspector and you should see a grayed out "UIViewController" in the first field. In that field, type in the name of the .h or .m file that you want it to connect to (Start typing PizzaDecorator... and it should do a little auto-complete thing). Then hit ENTER.

When you open up the Assistant Editor, make sure that the file that you are trying to drag and drop to is, in fact, the correct file.

If you have done all as said above, then it should work.

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. I've tried to do this before to no avail. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5ixtcps.png

Comment: Huh. Strange. Try adding them in programmatically (i.e. @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *test;) and then when the little circle appears next to it, drag and drop to your UIView.

Comment: That works and always has (and the apps seem to run okay), but I'm trying to solve the problem that it won't add automatically.

Comment: Well, if it works like that, then it should work the other way. Bug in your XCode? Try to get a previous version (like 4.6.2 or something) and install that. Otherwise, ummmmmmmmmmmmmmm...... yeah....

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid of. Uninstalling and reinstalling hasn't been working, I was hoping I was making a mistake. What's the best way to downgrade my copy of Xcode?

Comment: @user2597451 Sorry for the wait, but Apple seems to have a web page down for their xcode downloads. Normally, you would just go [to this page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and click the "View Downloads". There you should see various versions of XCode, just download and install accordingly.

Comment: Just had the same happen for me in Xcode 5. Never seen this before.  Tried dragging an IBOutlet into the viewController header and got that message.  Restarting Xcode worked for me.  Why, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on @ChrisHarrison's answer, those things did not work for me, but deleting the derived data as in I got it to work by deleting the derived data as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182672/1449799

Comment: Deleting derived data or cleaning rebuilding project or closing xcode did not work for me.
I just created new viewcontroller class then copied- pasted old one but not class name included. so it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the files (only the references) and add the files again.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case, the thing that worked (it's a litle weird, but worked) is the following:

Try to add a datasource (ex. an extension to the ViewController like a UITableViewDataSource). Xcode will try to reload the ViewController. Then I wrote some method of the protocol (in the beginning Xcode did not autocomplete the methods, but wrote it out manually), then I added the IBOutlets, and then lastly, I removed the datasource.

Example:

```
class TestViewController:UIViewController{
    // This viewController presents “Could not find any information for  class named ViewController”
}

extension TestViewController:UITableViewDataSource{
    //Add Some methods of the protocol, Xcode will try to autocomplete and then it's going to reload the class, from then you can add your IBOulets / Actions .. And remove this extension if you don't need it otherwise.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the view I had specified a custom class for was failing to be compiled by interface builder. It was marked `@IBDesignable`.

Removing `@IBDesignable`, and then adding my outlets, and then marking it as `@IBDesignable` resolved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to delete Derived Data for the project

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexEnable 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check from finder Xcode whether closed or not.

Force quit Xcode and restart.

Product > Clean

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the Xcode indexing process had stopped running. Rebooting my Mac fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project folder and delete derived data folder

if you cant find the derived data, go to finder and go to

```
 ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/"project"
```

(replace "project" name with project name)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is in most cases just Xcode acting out, but in my case none of the suggested actions managed to fix the issue and I believe it was a mistake I made when trying to rename my project, so I ended up creating a new project and importing everything over.

This eventually fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a same class name and xcode could not recognize which one I am targeting so be careful in selecting name of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to connect a button as an action with no arguments and sender as `UIButton`. The result was-

```
@IBAction func comma1() {

}
```

and I could put the rest of the `outlets` or `actions`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that there is a syntax error on the project.
Everything worked fine after solving the error.
I am working with xCode 11

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after I applied the MVC architecture, after I changed the location of the info.plist file.

After specifying the new file location, the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode Storyboard error**

> Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named <controller_name>

This error also is occurred when you rename `Main.storyboard`(e.g. to `Foo.storyboard`) and try to connect storyboard with controller

To fix it just set correct name in Info.plist `UISceneStoryboardFile` string (in out case - Foo)

Answer (score -1):

You know what worked for me...

I save the application, closed Xcode and then re-opened the project file... good to go!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?