# Xcode Swift: Could not insert new outlet connection

Tags: swift, xcode

Im getting following error when I'm trying to connect outlet from my search bar.
[image]

How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you have a ViewController class defined in your project? (usually there is when starting a new template)

Comment: possible duplicate question please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082979/2741603

Comment: I don't know where I can't check that :(

Comment: I have tried that before adarshaU, but it does not work for me

Comment: make sure your viewcontroller class binded to IB.if it's then 1.clear derived data. 2. Re-add class name .3. restart xcode and perform clean then build.

Comment: Share screenshot of your viewcontroller code

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jk9y4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923881/could-not-insert-new-outlet-connection-could-not-find-any-information-for-the-c)

Answer (score 6):

1. **Clean** the Project

[image]

2. **Build** and then Run.
3. Try to add the outlets again, it will work this time.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and I searched for several days how to fix this. I tried every solution that I could find, but without any luck.

I started looking in my git history on which branch the error occurred. I found a solution after several days.

I was working on a big project and I wanted to speed up my build speed and I changed some stuff in the build settings. The build setting that caused this issue was 'Swift compiler - Optimization level'. I changed the default value (No optimization) to 'Optimize for speed' and this caused the issue "Could not insert new outlet connection".

I hope I can help others with this solution because I lost a lot of time with it.

[image: This is what it should be]

Answer (score 1):

In my case nothing worked

1) Deleting Class

2) Disconnecting the @IBOutlet

3) Manually Creating @IBOutlet Connections

**The thing which did work was to restart XCode**

After restart you can easily connect them without errors

Answer (score 0):

Check that ViewController is correct or not?

Or

Clear class name in storyboard and edit again and also in class file

Or

quit Xcode and reopen and try that

Comment: How can I check that ViewController is correct or not? Sorry, but I'm new to Xcode. I have no idea how to do any of those two possible solutions that you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect the other way, ie from the IBOutlet to the search bar ?
In such a case, a clean of build border plus a reopen of the project should solve the problem.

Comment: No, I can't. I've tried that as well but it does not work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this question. But, I think it was because you made a change to the class name on your swift file and it hasn't been saved yet. (The file is grayed out)

My solution: Try building it (Command + B), then connect it again.

Answer (score 0):

I created two classes with the same name in the project which gave me this error. By deleting one class file the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to make the call the other way around, example: @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

I connected the .swift file to the .storyboard

Answer (score -3):

Error? Just check the locations of UI class file(swift) 
and UI builder file(xib or storyboard). Best is "Relative to Group"

[image]

Comment: You should clarify what all the arrows mean in the photo, and expand upon this answer.

Comment: Please don’t post photos of a dirty screen... Make proper screenshots and add explanations. Thanks.

Comment: Just first for me with stackoverflow.com. thanks for your comment