# Why Can't I Connect A Button To My View Controller In Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a new app and I started as I usually do which is creating a button, but when I hit CONNECT. A message poped up.

It says: Could not insert new action connection: Could not find any information for the class named ViewController

If anyone knows why this is happening, please tell me!

Thanks!

BTW: I won't let me post images because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: How did you create your @IBOutlet button?

Comment: Also make sure your class matches the view controller on your storyboard in the class inspector and in your .swift file.

Comment: I created the @IBOutlet button by clicking down on the button while holding down control and then draging the mouse to the spot in the code like I usually do.

Comment: And the class does match the view controller on my storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These resources should be able to help you:
["Could not find any information for class named ViewController"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735182/could-not-find-any-information-for-class-named-viewcontroller) and [Could not insert new outlet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288773/could-not-insert-new-outlet-connection)