# How to install XcodeColors with Xcode 4.6?

Tags: installation, environment-variables, osx-snow-leopard, xcode4.6, xcode-scheme

Using [CoconutKit](https://github.com/defagos/CoconutKit), I wanted to see all their logs in color. Sadly, I did not get [XcodeColors](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) to run.

Supposedly, I was to copy XcodeColors into the Xcode plug-ins path:

> /Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

Not only the Plug-ins folder did not exist, but *the whole folder chain starting with Developer was not there. I created all of the folders* and put the files where they nominally belonged. I created the environment variable for my current scheme in Xcode:

[image: image: "setting XcodeColors = YES environment variable"]

and eagerly ran my program.

No colored debug logs. Any ideas why that could be?

Thanks, A.

Edit: The first answer was quite correct. Still it did not work. But for [another reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703054/xcode-4-creating-a-uiview-xib-not-properly-connecting?rq=1) I removed all the *DerivedData* for my project, restarted Xcode and then 'voilà': I have not been so happy to see an ERROR warning, yet - it was red.
[image: image: "debugger text with a red ERROR warning and the crash log"]

Comment: can you provide a more clear steps as to how you got it to work please ?

Comment: I used the first option of the installation [instructions](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors#xcodecolors-installation-instructions-for-xcode-4). Then I created the environment variable for my scheme in Xcode. For that you click your scheme with the left mouse button to open the scheme editor and to find the table for the environment variables. Then, if it still does not work, as in my case, delete all the derived data for your project. It worked for me after that. If you need more info, pose a separate question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) for XcodeColors state:

```
Copy this folder to "~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeColors.xcplugin"
```

(i.e. your home directory, not the global directory `/Library/Application Support/Developer/...`).

Comment: Thank you for this information.

It made me find out how to [show hidden files](http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder) in Finder (curtesy of [Gina](http://gina.kinja.com/)). There must be something else, as well, because it still does not work.

In the hidden library there already was a folder named _Xcode_, but it was a sibling of the folder called _Shared_. There was not yet a folder named _Xcode_ inside the folder _Shared_, so I copied that.

Apart from typos, what else could I have missed?

Comment: @AOphagen You might be best approaching the author of XcodeColors; he's likely to have seen this issue many times.

Comment: Thank you. For [another reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703054/xcode-4-creating-a-uiview-xib-not-properly-connecting?rq=1) I removed all the _DerivedData_ for my project, restarted Xcode and then 'voilà': I have not been so happy to see an ERROR warning, yet - it was red.
I am giving you answer the green thumbs up now.

Comment: for other readers, who tries to find this folder the ~library folder is hidden in mac. u need to unhide it.

and the home directory normally it means the user's home directory e.g. ~mike/ would be the user mike's home directory.

hope it helps for some readers.

Comment: Start Terminal.app and type `chflags nohidden ~/Library`.